# Optimize the time to run fixed effects in an R lm() model

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to run a regression model that includes fixed effects for cities in the united states.  I have over 10,000,000 million rows and 600 cities.  The code below works, but  it is really slow.  When including a factor for a variable with lots of levels, is there any way to run the model faster.

```
x <- data.frame(
    a = sample( 1:1000, 1000000 , replace=T),
    cityfips = sample( 1:250, 1000000 , replace=T),
    d = sample( 1:4, 1000000 , replace=T)
)

system.time(a1 <- lm( a~cityfips+d  , x ) )
system.time(a2 <- lm( a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  , x ) )




> system.time(a1 <- lm( a~cityfips+d  , x ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.22    0.00    0.22 
> system.time(a2 <- lm( a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  , x ) )
   user  system elapsed 
  95.65    0.97   96.62 
> system.time(a3 <- slm( a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  , x ) )
   user  system elapsed 
   4.58    2.06    6.65
```

Comment: hmmm i actually see the issue you might have.. it's the model.matrix that is killing your lm and the duplicate question does not actually address this issue

Comment: you can try using a sparseMatrix, http://web.mit.edu/r/current/lib/R/library/SparseM/html/slm.html, but seems like it's very experimental

Comment: @StupidWolf - That did it, I updated the question giving you attribution, wish I could up vote you.  Thanks

Comment: No worries... ok i checked, seems like coefficients are the same. Yeah you needa be careful, the fitting is done slightly differently. You can read more http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/sparse/SparseM.pdf

Comment: in general, you shouldn't edit your question to include the answer.  If there are aspects to the answer that aren't covered in the existing answers, you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have that many factors, constructing the model.matrix in `lm()` will take up most of the time, one way is to use sparseMatrix like in `glmnet` and there are two packages, `sparseM`, `MatrixModels` that allows lm onto sparseMatrix:

```
set.seed(111)
x <- data.frame(
    a = sample( 1:1000, 1000000 , replace=T),
    cityfips = sample( 1:250, 1000000 , replace=T),
    d = sample( 1:4, 1000000 , replace=T)
)

library(SparseM)
library(MatrixModels)
library(Matrix)

system.time(f_lm <- lm( a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  , x )  )
   user  system elapsed 
 75.720   2.494  79.365  
system.time(f_sparseM <- slm(a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  , x ))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.373   3.952  10.646
system.time(f_modelMatrix <- glm4(a~as.factor(cityfips) + d  ,data=x,sparse=TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.878   0.335   2.219
```

The closest I can find is glm4 in `MatrixModels`, but you can see below the coefficients are the same as the fit using lm:

```
all.equal(as.numeric(f_sparseM$coefficients),as.numeric(f_lm$coefficients))
[1] TRUE
all.equal(as.numeric(f_lm$coefficients),as.numeric(coefficients(f_modelMatrix)))
[1] TRUE
```

One other option besides `glm4` in `MatrixModels` is to use lm.fit (as pointed out by @BenBolker:

```
lm.fit(x=Matrix::sparse.model.matrix(~as.factor(cityfips) + d,data=x),y=x$a)
```

This gives you a list as like `lm.fit()` normally and you cannot apply functions such as `summary()` etc.

Authors of both package warn about it being experimental so there might still be some differences compared to `stats::lm` , take care to check.

Comment: you can also use `Matrix::sparse.model.matrix` and pass the results to `lm.fit()`

Comment: thanks for pointing it out @BenBolker. I was looking at it, but was unsure what OP needs the lm object for. For example if you need to do summary(..) it will not work on lm.fit() or MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse()

Comment: but yes, you are right, maybe I include it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

check out the [lfe package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/lfe.pdf). I've not dug into the details of the algorithm but at least in my experience it's produced exactly the same results as `lm()` in fractions of the time.

as a bonus it makes it easy to cluster standard errors so you don't need to do any clustering and/or sandwich estimator business afterward, although the syntax for doing so is a little unusual